# keep count on an object in rails for a session and display it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to create an app that can keep count of a users correct answers and display them. How do I access this for a session and display it. I have the count set-up as global  variable which is probably wrong to start with.

My app asks a random question and if the user clicks on the correct answer it reloads the page with a new question. If incorrect it directs them to a new page. How would I display the correct answer count?

My users and sessions are set-up like the ruby on rails tutorial by michael hartl.

```
controller.rb

    @@ruby_functs_count = 0

    def ruby_functs
    @symbols = { 
  "abort" => "Terminates program. If an exception is raised (i.e., $! isn't nil), its error message is displayed.",
  "Array( obj)" => "Returns obj after converting it to an array using to_ary or to_a."
 }
@random = []
@random2 = []
  rando = @symbols.sort_by {rand}
  rando = rando.each { |k,v|  @random << k and @random2 << v}
  @sym = @random2[0]
  @answer = @random[0]
  @sym2 = @random[0..10].sort_by {rand}
end

sessions_controller.rb

    class SessionsController < ApplicationController

def sign_in(user)
    cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
    self.current_user = user
end

def new
end

def create
    user = User.find_by_email(params[:session][:email].downcase)
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
        sign_in user
        redirect_to user
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end

ruby_functs.html.erb

    <% for @random in @sym2 
     if @random == @answer
        x = cards_ruby_functs_path %>
        <li class="btn btn-small btn-info flash"><%= link_to "#{@random}", x %></li>
        <% else 
            x = cards_wrong_path %>

            <li class="btn btn-small btn-info flash"><%= link_to "#{@random}", x %></li>
 <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

Comment: Why not to save any user related data (and any counters you want too) in database?

Comment: I actually went with a database to store the questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pfhahf, i don't know where to start...

yes, it's a bad idea to use class variables like `@@ruby_functs_count` to store state. this is not a global variable, that would look like `$ruby_functs_count` (using global variables es even worse).

what you could do as a start:

**use ids**

when you know the id of the answer, you can store it easily and compare the results:

```
# application_controller
Question = Struct.new(:q, :a)
QUESTIONS = { 
  1 => Question.new("abort", "Terminates..."),
  2 => Question.new("Array( obj)", "Returns..."),
}
```

this example uses a struct to represent the data and stores it in a constant, so that it is readable and with easy access like:

```
question = QUESTIONS[1]
question.q # => "about"
question.a # => "Terminates..."
```

you can then keep track of the user-interaction in some session field:

```
session[:answered] ||= [] # init the session key if it's empty
session[:answered] << params[:question_id] # store the id so that you can work on it
```

i hope that this helps you go further with your code.

Comment: Thanks, I think that's perfect. I've only been working on rails for a few weeks, but I knew there had to be a better way all around. Oh and ya my bad, I meant class variable. Thanks again for the help :) The SO community is the bees knees. I'll post a link to the app here once I'm finished.